# Haskell pattern matching on vectors

Tags: haskell, vector, pattern-synonyms

Is it possible to use list style pattern matching on vectors?

ie

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

f :: V.Vector a -> a
f (x:xs) = x
```

gives an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-XViewPatterns` *can* let you do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
module VecViewPats where

import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

uncons :: Vector a -> Maybe (a, Vector a)
uncons v = if V.null v
  then Nothing
  else Just (V.unsafeHead v, V.unsafeTail v)

vsum :: Num a => Vector a -> a
vsum (uncons -> Just (a,av)) = a + vsum av
vsum (uncons -> Nothing) = 0
```

Or `-XLambdaCase`

```
import Control.Category ((>>>))
-- ...
vsum :: Num a => Vector a -> a
vsum = uncons >>> \case
  Just (a,av) -> a + vsum av
  Nothing     -> 0
```

But honestly, that's seems like a bit of a code smell as you're using one data structure (`Vector`) as another (`[]`) which suggests that maybe your choice of data structure is off.

If you really just want to treat it like a list for the purposes of some algorithm, why not use [`toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList)?

Comment: Or you can use a pattern synonym: `pattern x ::: xs <- (uncons -> Just (x, xs))`

Comment: Is view pattern still needed no we have guard pattern ?

Comment: I am using functions from the `Statistics` library, which work on `Vectors`. So I apparently would have to `toList` to work over my list then `fromList` to use the functions? which seems to defeat the point?

Comment: matthias: it depends. Do you want to convert a vector to another vector of the same length? Use `fmap`.  A single value? Use `fold`.  A selection of the elements? Use `filter`. With both lists and vectors, specialized higher-order functions exist to make various tasks both more efficient and easier for others to read.

Answer (score 5):

@Cactus has pointed out `-XPatternSynonym` (introduced in 7.8) combined with `-XViewPattern` can be used to pattern match on vectors. I am here to extend his comment a bit further.

```
pattern Empty <- (V.null -> True)
```

The above defines a pattern synonym `Empty` for the empty vector. The `Empty` pattern matches against an empty vector using view pattern (`V.null -> True`). However, it cannot be used as an expression elsewhere, i.e. a *uni*-directional synonym, since the system doesn't really know what `Empty` is as a Vector (we only know that `null v` is `True` but there could be other vectors giving `True` as well).

To remedy this, a `where` clause can be added specifying that Empty actually is a empty vector, i.e. a *bi*-directional synonym, as well as a type signature:

```
pattern Empty :: Vector a
pattern Empty <- (V.null -> True) where Empty = V.empty
```

This pattern synonym can be used to define `uncons` without an if expression:

```
uncons :: Vector a -> Maybe (a, Vector a)
uncons Empty = Nothing
uncons v     = Just (unsafeHead v, unsafeTail v)
```

We use `uncons` to define uni-directional synonym. Note I don't make it bi-directional since `cons` is costly for vector:

```
pattern (:<|)  :: a -> Vector a -> Vector a
pattern x :<| xs <- (uncons -> Just (x, xs))
```

Anyway, we are finally able to pattern match on vectors just like lists:

```
vsum :: Num a => Vector a -> a 
vsum Empty = 0
vsum (x :<| xs) = x + vsum xs
```

A complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/L-TChen/4c0dc8d270d2b14ee23b392717c91a38).

Answer (score 1):

Vectors aren't intended for that kind of pattern matching--they were created to give Haskell O(1) lists, or lists that can be accessed from any point efficiently.

The closest thing to what you wrote would be something like this:

```
f v = V.head v
```

Or, if recursion is what you are looking for, the `tail` function will get the rest of the list.

But if you are trying to do something that moves along a list like that, there are Vector equivalents of functions such as `foldl`, `find`, `map`, and the like. It depends on what you intend to do.

Comment: I am trying to run functions which `f :: Vector a -> a` on a vector, but I want to move across the vector and recalculate (while keeping the other values) as each new item is added. ie on `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]`, i want to `[f [1], f [1,2], f [1,2,3]..]` and so on.

Comment: @matthias that's a [scan](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:34)

Comment: @rampion sorry, I am bit confused. Isn't a scan a cumulative function that passes a result on to the next iteration? How would I write a scan function for what I have above? I appreciate your help.

Comment: It depends on the definition of `f`. If there exists `g` s.t. `f [a_0...a_i] = g (f [a_0...a_{i-1}]) a_i` forall `i` and `b` s.t. `f [] = b`, then `scanl g b [a_0 .. a_n]` will yield `[ f [], f [a_0], f [a_0,a_1], f [a_0, a_1, a_2] ..., f [a_0, a_1, ... a_n ] ]`.  Such implementations are often more efficient, as they only need to do `O(n)` work, rather than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If not, then what you need is a version of `inits` for Data.Vector, which wouldn't be too hard to implement using [`init`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:init).  `inits [ a_0, a_1 ... a_n ] = [ [], [a_0], [a_0, a_1], [a_0, a_1, a_2], ..., [a_0, a_1, ..., a_n] ]`, so you could do `fmap f . inits`.